# How to replace files in fat partition in u-boot stage

Tags: u-boot, mmc

The system has an MMC with FAT partition. The FAT partition contains some files, two of them are called "file_A" and "file_B".
I need to prepare a script to toggle between file_A and file_B at the u-boot stage without knowing the file's size in advance.
I thought to use fatload and fatwrite commands.
I loaded the file to the RAM using fatload without issues using:
fatload mmc 0:1 0x0 file_A

Now I have issues with copying the file residing in the RAM to the fat partition using fatwrite, again I don't now the file size in advance (I've noticed that the fatload print information contains the file size, maybe I can use it somehow?).

Answer (score 0):

Most commands to load something in to memory set the `filesize` variable to how much was loaded in to memory.

Comment: Hi. I've used the filesize variable like you suggested but I encountered with some problem. It's not related to the original problem. It's seems that the copy corrupt the partition. I've used the fatload command to load the file to address 0x0 in the RAM. then I've used the fatwrite and the filesize variable to copy the file from the RAM. When comparing the original file with the new file I received this error : "fat_get_cluster: invalid cluster chain"

Comment: Without knowing what version you're running it's possible it's an issue that has been fixed upstream.  Otherwise please bring this bug up on the U-Boot mailing list, thanks.

Comment: I will update regarding the version tomorrow. The u-boot suppose to update the FAT allocation table right?.